# how to get data from .env laravel using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel, environment

> how to  get variable from .env laravel using angularjs ,

for example 
in php $a = .env('VARIABLE_A')
in js  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

 var x = <?php echo .env('VARIABLE_A') ?>

</script>
```

Now in js `x` will contain the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should [prefix them with `MIX_`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables)